# No puedo leer un array

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_raw);
foreach ($xml->$user-agent as $ua):
    print $ua->String;
endforeach;
```

Y no hace nada, per imprime esto:
Notice: Undefined variable: user in /var/www/html/u.php on line 4

Notice: Use of undefined constant agent - assumed 'agent' in /var/www/html/u.php on line 4

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/u.php on line 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que en el XML, la etiqueta tiene un nombre con un guión (`user-agent`), así que no puedes acceder a ese valor usando la notación `$xml->$user-agent`. En la [documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), puedes encontrar una nota sobre esto (traducción mía):

> En un documento XML, para acceder a elementos que contengan un caracter no permitido en la nomenclatura de PHP (p.e. guiones) el nombre del elemento debe ir entrecomillado y entre llaves.

Así que lo que debes hacer es usar la notación con llaves, que en tu caso sería algo así:

```
$xml->{'user-agent'}
```